# Problem in XCode ( I need help )

Tags: xcode

I having a program error on the xcode . That I can't solve it . 
Can someone seriously help me to solve these problem . 
**(Thank In Advance )**

These is the problem :

error: 'colorSpace' undeclared (first use in this function)

cvReleaseImage(&small_image);

```
    // Create canvas to show the results
    CGImageRef imageRef = imageView.image.CGImage;

    //unsigned char *rawData = malloc(imageView.image.size.width*imageView.image.size.height*4);
     ;
    CGContextRef contextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, imageView.image.size.width, imageView.image.size.height,
                                                    8, imageView.image.size.width * 4,
                                                     **colorSpace**, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast|kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault);
    CGContextDrawImage(contextRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, imageView.image.size.width, imageView.image.size.height), imageRef);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the 'colorSapce' before calling CGBitmapContextCreate().
e.g CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
if it's still error, modify '**colorSapce**'  to 'colorSapce'.
hope those is used for you .